# MySql: Delete a row with INNER JOIN when there is no corresponding row in Foreign Table

Tags: mysql, .net, asp.net-core

I'm writing a simple API and I have one lingering issue that I cant wrap my head around.  I have a Ticket table and a Reply table. There is a Foreign Key on the Replies table, relating to the ticket id.  Im using the following to Delete a ticket and all of the corresponding replies in the Reply table:

```
DELETE FROM tickets, replies USING tickets INNER JOIN replies WHERE tickets.ticketid = @thisId AND tickets.ticketid = replies.ticketid;
```

This does not, as expected, delete a row that does not have any corresponding replies but will still return 200.  I have tried so many different ways to use this statement to include BOTH a ticket row that HAS a relationship on the replies table, and one that does not.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to delete record on tickets that has no replies.

```
DELETE a FROM tickets a LEFT JOIN replies b ON a.ticketid = b.ticketid WHERE a.ticketid = @thisId AND b.ticketid is null;
```

But did not test yet with sample table.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely deletes records where table b (replies) returns null.  I was looking for a solution that would _both_ Delete from tickets and replies when `ticketid` matched both, _and_ Delete from tickets when there is no matching reply.  The issue i am running into is that when I use the script I posted originally but change it to `LEFT JOIN` I get a DBNull from .Net.  I was just hoping that there might be some SQL magic that would make it so I don't have to deal with DBNull in the first place.